# Unable to configure the Route53 to point to CloudFront Distribution for the static website hosted on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I am trying to deploy my static website to S3 configuring CloudFront in front of it. But I am not able to configure Route53 to integrate with CloudFront. Below is what I have done so far.

I create an S3 bucket enabling static hosting and allowing public access. Then I deployed/ uploaded the files. I can access my website through the S3 website static URL, http://www.waiyanhein.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/.

I have my own domain called, waiyanhein.com.

I am trying to configure the CloudFront in front of my static website. So I created a CloudFront distribution. For the Origin Domain Name, I chose the S3 Bucket's static website URL. Then I chose "Compress Objects Automatically" as YES. In the "Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs)" text field, I entered, "waiyanhein.com". Then I created the CloudFront distribution. Now my CloudFront distribution is up and running.

Then I tried to configure Route53 pointing to the CloudFront distribution. I tried creating a record choosing "Alias to CloudFront distribution" option. But I can't find my CloudFront distribution in the resources as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image]

What's wrong with my configuration?

I have sort of found out something in the CloudFront distribution too. When I edit the CloudFront distribution, the Alternative domains field is empty for some reasons. Then I entered the domains and clicked save. Then I got the following error.

```
com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.model.InvalidViewerCertificateException: To add an alternate domain name (CNAME) to a CloudFront distribution, you must attach a trusted certificate that validates your authorization to use the domain name. For more details, see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html#alternate-domain-names-requirements (Service: AmazonCloudFront; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidViewerCertificate; Request ID: 2d1bacd5-794c-46e5-beec-70b24fab83a6; Proxy: null)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it does not appear automatically in the dropdown then AWS would be filtering this as it believes that the exact domain you intend to use is not usable for any CloudFront distributions in the account.

Please check the following are correct:

- The exact record is covered by the alternative name(s) attached to the CloudFront distribution.
- The CloudFront distribution is finished rolling out.

From the interface for the Alias value you should be able to paste the CloudFront domain name with a trailing `.` although in this new interface certain actions do not currently appear to work. If this is the case for you revert back to the original interface by clicking on the `Switch to old console` link on the left hand side of the screen and attempt from here.

**Additional Comments**

The screenshot indicates that an alternative domain that is being specified does not have a matching ACM certificate in `us-east-1` which is attached to your CloudFront distribution.

If you do not have one generate a new one, then attach it to your CloudFront distribution when you add the alternative domain name.

Comment: Hi, I have spotted something in the CloudFront distribution regarding the alternate domains. I have updated the question. Please, have a look at it.

Comment: Have you got an ACM certificate in us-east-1 which covers the full domain you intend to use?

Comment: I just requested and the status is showing "Pending" validation.

Comment: Once you complete the validation steps it should complete within a few hours (but normally much quicker)

Comment: OK. I will wait. Thanks.

Comment: Just make sure you've followed the validation (either dns or email validation)

Comment: I have chosen email validation. But I have not got any email yet.

Comment: Is the email you're checking on the whois record? This is who will receive the email

Comment: I have requested another certificate choosing DNS option. I can export the configuration file. Do I need to create records using the values in the file?

Comment: Nevermind, now it is saying "Issued". I am figuring out the CloudFront distribution issue now.

Comment: It still does not work. I switched to old console. I created a CNAME alias record "www.waiyanhein.com" pointing to "d143lqjipibrh9.cloudfront.net.".

Comment: It works finally. I needed to remove trailing "." and charged to "A" record.

Comment: fwiw this: `The exact record is covered by the alternative name(s) attached to the CloudFront distribution.` was my issue and a pretty common one by my understanding after talking to others about this.